# Delay() in the q module

Tags: node.js, promise, q

I am using nodejs and learning promises using the q module.

I'm misunderstanding the `delay()` fn in the q module, I think .

When I run this code:

```
chain
  .then (function() {console.log('starting');})
  .then (function() {console.log('waiting 2500ms');})
  .delay(2500)
  .then (function() {console.log('done');})
  .then (function() {console.log('waiting 5500ms');})
  .delay(5500)
  .then (function() {console.log('done');})
  .then(function() {console.log('waiting 4500ms');})
  .delay(4500)
  .then (function() {console.log('done');})
  .then(function() { process.exit(0);});
```

I expect to see delays of the indicated times.
The first delay seems to occur.
The second delay doesn't really seem to be 5500ms.
The third delay, expected 4500ms, doesn't seem to happen at all.

I am understanding "delay(x)" to mean "then, delay for x milliseconds".  Is this incorrect? Am I misunderstanding?

If I modify the code to replace each `delay(x)` with

```
   .then(function() {sleep.usleep(x * 1000);})
```

...then it works as I expect.

Can someone please explain? 
Thanks.

Comment: **WARNING**: The information in this thread regards an old version of Q and is no longer accurate. New versions work as you'd expect with delay.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The delay() is a little different than what anyone else would expect, which makes it uglier to chain them. I learned it from the discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/q-continuum/nOYkOcGeGL8/AQGjMrEyjKIJ).

```
Q()
  .then (function() {console.log('starting');})
  .then (function() {console.log('waiting 2500ms');})
  //.delay(2500)
  .then( function () { return Q().delay( 2500 ); } )
  .then (function() {console.log('done');})
  .then (function() {console.log('waiting 5500ms');})
  //.delay(5500)
  .then( function () { return Q().delay( 5500 ); } )
  .then (function() {console.log('done');})
  .then(function() {console.log('waiting 4500ms');})
  //.delay(4500)
  .then( function () { return Q().delay( 4500 ); } )
  .then (function() {console.log('done');})
  .then(function() { process.exit(0);});
```

Hopefully they will fix it soon.

Comment: This was actually fixed a few weeks ago (https://github.com/kriskowal/q/pull/326?source=cc).  Try making sure you're on the latest version, I think 0.9.6 should work as you expect it to.

Comment: hmmmm, I'm on 0.9.6. The behavior I reported occurred with 0.9.6